# Get a value of a object that is within another object. Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I want get a value of a object that is within another object. The e.Model object has within "attributes object" and this have the car object.
I need the value category: "EEE" of car object

**Principal object**

```
e.Model {cid: "c770", attributes: Object, collection: s, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}
```

**Object attributes**

```
car: Object
```

**Object Car**

```
car: Object
abs: false
airbags: false
airconditioning: true
airportdesk: true
assistedsteering: false
automatictransmission: true
category: "EEE"
diesel: false
doors: 5
engine: null
frigorifico: false
gps: false
groupid: "WFAD"
groupname: "nombregrp"
guaranteed: false
id: "MODE000697"
imgsrc: "http://youcarrental.blob.core.windows.net/cars/Range Rover Sport_lg.gif"
isotermo: false
m3: ""
modelname: "Range Rover SPORT"
radio: false
rampa: false
spaces: "5"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You mean something like `e.Model.attributes.car.category`?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for my English ^^

Comment: That's backbone.js ?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?